# failed to use iconv to change encoding in shell

Tags: command-line, iconv

I have a file to convert its encoding.
In terminal, I have :

```
$file -i *
```

and it turns out `text/plain; charset=us-ascii`

Then I have this command line :

```
$ iconv -f us-ascii -t UTF-8 oldfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

It turns out a message: `iconv: illegal input sequence at position 2575661`

I searched and found that this suggests there are invalid sequences (for instance this page https://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/07/13/some-useful-iconv-functionality/). I am wondering what would be the most reliable way to convert the encoding to the most appropriate encoding to sqlite, and how to find the invalid sequences? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it help the process if you typed `$ iconv -c -f us-ascii -t UTF-8 oldfile.txt > newfile.txt`

...otherwise try: `$ iconv -f US-ASCII -t UTF-8 oldfile.txt > newfile.txt` and with the `-c`-flag.